# How do I get the Type via getElementById?

Tags: svelte

Here is my Script tag in a Svelte Project.

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(async () => {
        await import('@material/mwc-drawer'); 
    });

    function onNavClick() {
        const drawer = this.getElementById('mat-drawer');
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do here is get some typing on my element which for the sake of learning is `id = mat-drawer`.

In the end either I want to do this:

```js
 const drawer = this.getElementById('mat-drawer') as Drawer;
```

or

```js
  const drawer: Drawer = this.getElementById('mat-drawer')!;
```

But I don't get how to import the `Drawer` in this context?

Edit:

I would expect I am seeking type information only here. However this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { Drawer } from '@material/drawer'; 

    onMount(async () => {
        await import('@material/mwc-drawer');
    });

    function onNavClick() {
        const drawer = this.getElementById('mat-drawer') as Drawer;
    }
</script>
```

fails with this:

`This import is never used as a value and must use 'import type' because 'importsNotUsedAsValues' is set to 'error'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is it, that you stress about something for a long time, then hit Stack Overflow and then in the process of being at your final straw, you find a solution?

The solution is `import type`. I have never seen this in my life but now that I know this is a thing, I naturally understand why this is a thing.

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import type { MDCDrawer } from '@material/drawer';  

    onMount(async () => {
        // use the custom component in markup
        await import('@material/mwc-drawer');
    });

    function onNavClick() {
        // get the actual type in typescript
        const drawer = this.getElementById('mat-drawer') as MDCDrawer;
    }
</script>
```